# is there a way I can get rid of the google maps error 400?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-api

[image]I am trying to get the directions on an app I'm developing to work again. 24 hours ago everything was fine but now i get the error

'Unexpected response code 400 for [https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api'](https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api%27)

each time I try to get directions to a point on the map
here are the images[image: fi]

[image]

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That http response code stands for "bad request"
This means that you are making a client-side (eg syntactically) error in the request to the google maps server.

for more about the error code read https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400